# git - Merge conflict

Tags: git

I have a feature and master branch. The code is the same on the feature and master branch. I am doing a change in the feature branch and creating a PR to Master branch. I am getting merge conflict.

I am doing the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin <feature branch>
git commit
git pull origin HEAD
```

Most of the times, the automatic merge gets failed. I need to manually clone the master branch and needs to copy the changes in the feature branch to the master branch manually and push it to the master.

1. What needs to be done to make the automatic merge to be successful?
2. When I resolve the merge conflict manually, now, I am doing a PR and
   now the error message is "Cannot create a PR as the master and
   branch are up to date". What needs to be done to create a PR and
   then merge to the master?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to follow the proper order for handling merge.

1. First get the latest of both the branches locally.

```
git checkout master
git pull 
git checkout feature
git pull
```

2. Now, do a merge of master branch on top of feature branch, to have other master changes. If automatic merge can be done, it is done. git handles it automatically. you dont have to do anything. If automatic merge can't be done, you have to go through the conflicts and resolve it.

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

3. Once you resolve the conflicts, now your local feature is ahead of remote master. Now, you can raise pull request.

**To answer your questions:**

> - What needs to be done to make the automatic merge to be successful?
>     Nothing. If automatic merge is possible, it is done automatically.
> - When I resolve the merge conflict manually, now, I am doing a PR and
>     now the error message is "Cannot create a PR as the master and branch
>     are up to date". What needs to be done to create a PR and then merge
>     to the master?
>     It looks like your feature branch is just pointing to
>     master branch. It is not having additional changes. It could be that
>     some other team member has already created a PR and your feature
>     branch is upto date with master branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you say "the  code is the same on the feature and master branch", does that mean that the only direct editing happens on the feature branch which is then dutifully merged into master? If that is so, there *should* not be any conflicts.

The situation changes though after you *manually* changed the same code locations in master which you changed in the feature branch. These of course are conflicting edits. (If they are *exactly identical* to the byte I think git would not see a conflict, but I'm not sure, and it may be difficult to achieve.)

The thing is that these conflicts pop up again and again because your manual take-overs did not register as merges. Therefore, git tries to apply the same old — manually merged — commits again and again.

What may help here is git's [rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) feature. It registers and stores user-supplied solutions to conflicts and applies them to any future commits which encounter the same conflicts. So I suggest to activate rerere, do one merge the official way solving all conflicts, and from then on all future merges should work as they are supposed to.

**Alternatively (ad I'd actually recommend this) you can simply start over: Set up a new feature branch starting at the current head of master and avoid all problems with the old merge/edit mess.**